# Why does my Server wait for an incoming connection before continuing?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, serversocket

I have a Server Class with this code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket srvSocket = new ServerSocket(server_port);
    System.out.println("Server started on Port: " + server_port);

    System.out.println("here");
    new Thread(new ClientHandler(srvSocket.accept())).start();
    System.out.println("here2");
 }
```

and this ClientHandler Class (i need the Comparable aswell):

```
public class ClientHandler implements Comparable<ClientHandler>, Runnable {
    private final Socket cltSocket;

    public ClientHandler(Socket cltSocket) {
        this.cltSocket = cltSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

I want to get to `System.out.println("here2");`, but I need to connect one client to it first (which I don't want). I tried it with `Runnable` but that didn't fix it either.

Is there an error in my code or do I have to do something else to not have to connect to it?

Comment: The `accept()` call happens before your `start()`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis and how would I fix this/What should i use as the Socket? thanks

Comment: @phil330d If you want `println("test")` to happen before `accept()`, i.e. before it waits for connection, then move the `accept()` call into the `run()` method. Or move the print statement outside. Those both seem pretty straightforward solutions.

Comment: There is nothing to fix. `accept()` is supposed to happen before your `start()`. Otherwise the thread would be starting without a socket.

Comment: `accept()` blocks until a client connects, THEN you create the `ClientHandler` to process the new `Socket` that `accept()` returns. That is how this is supposed to work.  If you don't want to block your code waiting on `accept()`, you need to call it in a separate thread.